# How to connect two web APIs

Tags: c#, telerik-mvc

I have a web api app. In client side of app, I created special control for reporting. This control is using Telerik Reporting api. User can send different kind of request. Also, users can use reporting with browser. In browser user should authorize before reporting anything. But in my client app user already authorized and it should be able to use this control without authorization. How can I join my web api and Telerik reporting api?

Comment: this is too broad

Comment: You're going to need to provide a lot more detail before anyone can get close to writing an appropriate answer.